# Can which refer to a sentence in a restrictive relative clause?

Tags: grammar

From Andrew Radford, A. (2004) *English Syntax*: An Introduction, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge

> For Chomsky, the goal of the linguist is to determine what it is that
> native speakers know about their native language **which** enables them to
> speak and understand the language fluently: hence, the study of
> language is part of the wider study of cognition (i.e. what human
> beings know).

As I know,' which' refers to nouns or pronouns most of the time. Does **'which'** here refer to **'what it is that native speakers know about their native language'** ?

If not, what part does it refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *For Chomsky, the goal of the linguist is to determine* [*what it is that*
> *native speakers know about their native language*] *which enables them to*
> *speak and understand the language fluently*.

Yes: "which" refers to the expression "what it is that native speakers know about their native language", which is a noun phrase.

Note that the antecedent is called a 'fused' relative construction, where "what" means "that which".

Comment: Thanks! Does 'which' refer to the phrase that only 'what' introduces? Can it refer to other kinds of clauses?

Comment: @WingledTiger No: "which" can refer to almost anything. In your example it refers to the _what_ noun phrase.